# What kind of information is stored in the State Trie?

Tags: storage

I have read https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/storage

And I am curious what is actually stored in the State Trie.

Are extrinsics and events stored in the State Trie?

Comment: Shawn's storage deep dive is also worth a watch: https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/substrate-storage-deep-dive/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The state trie stores the state ;) Aka all the key value pairs that make up the state. This means that also runtime events are part of the state of each block. Extrinsics and headers are not part of the state trie. However, that depends on the runtime, if the runtime for whatever stores the data in the trie, then they would also be part of the state trie.